# SQL Server "n*" wildcard in contains problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a problem with SQL Server `contains`.

I have 2 data in some table, the code of data is `"CJK-7123"` and `"CJK-7890"`.
When I use SQL Server `contains` like this `"contains((table.code),'"n*"')"` in my select query, those of two data is still showing in my query, even though the code doesn't contain `n` character.

Comment: Tag your dbms and show the query.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please you let us know which database management system (e.g. MS SQL Server. you are using.